# How do I copy an object using a pointer?

Tags: object, c++11, copy, clone, virtual

I am learning C++ and our teacher ask us to use a copy function with a pointer. He gave us a similar code to this one but I can't figure out how to use the copy function:

```
class Animal
{
public:
    ...
    virtual Animal* copy() const =0;
}


class Dog : public Animal
{
public:
    ...
    virtual Animal* copy() const;
}


Animal* Dog::copy() const
{
    return new Dog(*this);
}


int main(){
Dog husky (…);
//Labrador = copy() of husky 
}
```

For example, what should I write to create a new objet (labrador) as a copy of an object (husky)?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, you don't actually need to use that `copy()` method at all, because you know that your `husky` object is a `Dog` and you want the copy to be another `Dog`.  So you can just write

```
Dog labrador(husky)
```

to construct `labrador` as a copy of `husky` using its copy constructor.

The point of the `copy()` method is that sometimes you just have an `Animal*` and you don't actually know what concrete type of animal it points to, so you don't know what type of new animal to create.  For example:

```
void example(Animal const *animal) {
    Animal *clonedAnimal = animal->copy();
}
```

The `example` function doesn't know what kind of `Animal` it's been given, but the animal object itself knows what it is, and the virtual function call lets that animal take care of copying itself.  If `animal` points to a `Dog` instance, the `Dog` version of `copy()` will run and construct a `Dog`.  If `animal` points to a `Cat`, the `Cat` version of the function will run and construct a new `Cat`.